# Probability that a set is a subset of another set and limits of probabilities

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\{A_n\}, \{B_n\}$ be two sequences of infinitely many finite sets $A_n, B_n$ satisfying 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(a \in B_n \ \mid \ a \in A_n) = 1,
$$
where, for each $n$, the element $a \in A_n$ is chosen uniformly at random. 
Is it true that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n \subseteq B_n) = 1?
$$
If so, what is a rigours proof?
Intuitively this seems to be true to me; also since 
$$
\mathbb{P}(a \in B_n \ \mid \ a \in A_n) = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(a \in A_n \cap B_n)}{\mathbb{P}(a \in A_n)} = \dfrac{|A_n \cap B_n|}{|A_n|}.
$$
Thank you.

Comment: your logic is correct.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of this question. What is being chosen randomly?

Comment: For the given assumption, the element $a$ is chosen uniformly at random from $A_n$. I then thought the 2nd would then follow from this assumption. I think the $n$'s are the ones being chosen at random for this 2nd? But please excuse me if there's anything that doesn't make sense. I'm fairly new to this. Thanks.

Comment: So the sets $A_n$ and $B_n$ are finite? Are they subsets of some given set? Is that set finite?

Comment: They are finite for each $n$, but why is this important?

Comment: I don't understand the set-up. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me an example of a set-up in which something like the above holds? Actually I also have mixed feelings about the implication of the assumption, because, for it to make sense, wouldn't the $n$'s have to be randomly chosen as well? For instance I think I read somewhere that there's no uniform distribution for the set of all natural numbers...

Comment: Why is the counting measure applicable here? You didn't specify that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are countable nor did you specify the probability measure.

Comment: So far the role of $a$ is unclear. Is it random? Is it fixed?

Comment: $a$ is chosen uniformly at random from $A_n$. The sets $A_n$, $B_n$ are countable (in fact finite for each $n$). The problem I have is with the implication, as I don't know if such $n$'s can also be chosen uniformly at random too?